# Is there any way to get serial number of ledger nano devices| Ledger Nano S,Ledger Nano X|Using Golang

Tags: javascript, go, hid, hardware-interface, ledger-nano-s

How can I retrieve the serial number of a **Ledger Nano S or Ledger Nano X** device using Golang or JavaScript? Is it possible to obtain the serial number from the device?, as I want to match it with a serial number assigned to each user in my code?

- I just want fetch serial number of connected device using Golang or JavaScript
- Or i just need to insert a unique ID to ledger nano device and fetch it